# Work Item failures migrating from TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

I've tried to get this to work a few times but running into the same problem.
A number of workitems are failing with the following error:

> OH-Connector-0143: Target system does not contain value : Resolved for field: State for entityType: Task

I've replaced the source projects WIT with the standard versions and I've tried to change the status on the work items referred to. All are Task type work items and have had state set to Resolved at some point although I have checked all failed items and none currently set to that state.

We are also seeing another failure message which I have assumed is caused by the above error which is:

> OpsHub-012010: Processing blocked - earlier event(s) for entity 6960 have to be processed first.

Additionally, no source has migrated. It is my assumption that this is because of the work item failures?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the failure is because the history of those workitems has already been persisted. It cannot be changed. You can update the current value of those WITs with an available state, but the historic revisions will remain the same.
OpsHub's Migration Tool migrates your entire history. Therefore, while processing the revisions where the State was 'Resolved', the issue is encountered.

And yes, the 'processing blocked' errors are because of the above error and the SCM migration will not start until the WIT is done due to linkage dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does that mean I can't use the tool to migrate this project? Or is there a way of editing the history to avoid the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid, the free tool will not work for scenarios where template customization was done (Especially for system fields) There are two options, 1. Let the tool migrate the WITs not having customization. Then separately migrate the SCM by creating a new migration and selecting only source data in the options. And manually bring over the failed entities. or 2. Use the commercial version of our tool which supports customization

Comment: I'll give option 1 a go first I think - there aren't that many items in this category. How do I get the tool to ignore the customised WIT? The only options under manage failures is to view the message or retry.

Comment: That's automatic. In the tool, whenever an entity fails for some reason, it does not affect the remaining WIT Types as well as other WIT of the same type. Only that particular entity and it's subsequent revisions are queued in the failure log. So, right now if you keep the migration running, it will continue with the rest of the WITs